# How to remove a Button added programatically

Tags: android, button, dynamic, android-linearlayout

I am adding buttons to a linear layout at runtime and need to add the functionality of removing them if the user desires. At the moment I have a button which opens a popup with a list consisting of the text for each button added. If possible, would I be able to have each onItemClick delete the corresponding button? If not, what would be the best way to remove a specific button?

Here is the code for adding buttons:

```
private void addButton(){
    LinearLayout lL = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.requirement_linear);
    lL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    p.setMargins(0,2,0,0);
    Button b = new Button(this);
    b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue_button); 
    b.setOnClickListener(openRequirement);
    b.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    String button_text = (index + 2) + ". " + requirement_list.get(index + 1).getName();
    b.setText(button_text);
    requirements_text.add(button_text);// requirements_text is an arraylist<string> which stores the text so I can display them in my popup to delete them.
    index ++;
    lL.addView(b,p);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use removeView() on your LinearLayout and pass your button. You can identify the button on the OnClick(View view) callback, the view there is the button.

as requested, here is an example.

```
final LinearLayout lL = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.requirement_linear);
Button b =  new Button(this);
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View button) {
        lL.removeView(button);
    }
});
lL.addView(b);
```

Alternatively you can use removeViewAt() to remove a child view by index. You can use the index of your 'list of text of buttons'. Assuming its a listview, you can try this.

```
lview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            lL.removeViewAt(position);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I'm not 100% how I would pass the appropriate button though to the on click method.

Comment: pass the appropriate button? the OnClick method has one View parameter that holds the button that triggered it. So i dont understand what you meant by 'passing' the button?

Comment: Would this example only work if the button removed itself then?

Comment: @Vayran sorry if i didnt understand your question fully. updated my answer with new example. hope i get it this time

Comment: Hey no worries, I appreciate all the help I can get. Your second solution is exactly what I'm looking for, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

here is how i hide and show the buttons

```
    Button b = new Button(this);
    b.setVisibility(View.GONE); // this will hide the button and it will now show
    b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // this will show the button if it was hidden before
```

Enjoy!